# clock_cast on gcc 12.2.1

Tags: c++, c++20, clock, system-clock

I must use the `utc_clock<>` feature of C++20. Before, I was using the date library from Howard Hinnant [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) but now I want to use the standard C++20 features (and not the date library).

The GCC version is:

> gcc version 12.2.1 20221020 [revision 0aaef83351473e8f4eb774f8f999bbe87a4866d7] (SUSE Linux)

He included an example to test the functionality:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::literals;    

auto start = clock_cast<utc_clock>(sys_days{2015y/July/1} - 500ms);
auto end = start + 2s;
for (auto utc = start; utc < end; utc += 100ms)
{
    auto sys = clock_cast<system_clock>(utc);
    auto tai = clock_cast<tai_clock>(utc);
    auto gps = clock_cast<gps_clock>(utc);
    cout << format("%F %T SYS  ==  ", sys)
              << format("%F %T %Z  ==  ", utc)
              << format("%F %T %Z  ==  ", tai)
              << format("%F %T %Z\n", gps);
}
```

In the CMakeLists.txt are the lines:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

But the compiler output is always:

```
/home/aces/Programs/FSLockingTest/datapacket.cpp:28: error: ‘clock_cast’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘clock_t’?
/home/aces/Programs/FSLockingTest/datapacket.cpp:28:20: error: ‘clock_cast’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘clock_t’?
   28 |         auto sys = clock_cast<system_clock>(utc);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    clock_t
```

Is `clock_cast` not implemented yet? If not, how to do the conversion? (I have tried from_sys for that but wasn't successful).

I tried to do several namespace variations; tt should compile without error.

Answer (score 2):

Not implemented yet.  But in progress: https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/Cxx20.html

Note that your format strings will need to be slightly altered: `"%F %T %Z"` -> `"{:%F %T %Z}"`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Then I will stay with the above mentioned library....